# How do I transfer a minecraft server backup to another server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

So a few friends and I made a server and my birthday is coming up where I will get a paid server instead of a free one from freemcserver.net. How do I transfer the world to the new server? The server isn't made yet but when it does get made I want to know how

Comment: What server are you planning on transferring this world to?

Comment: its not made yet but when it does get made i wanna know how @OKprogrammer

Comment: Hello? Can I please have some help here?

Comment: There are many different ways to upload a world to a server, and it can change substantially based on what host you are using. Because we don't know, we can't answer with 100% certainty that our advice will assist you and others.

Comment: i am using shockbyte

Comment: Ok, you might want to add that into the question and wait for someone to answer, as I am not experienced with this server system.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/). This should work for pretty much any hosting service, but I can tell you for certain that it works for shockbyte (which the asker has clarified they are using in the comments) because they have a [How To section for using FileZilla](https://shockbyte.com/billing/knowledgebase/40/How-to-use-FileZilla-for-FTP-File-Management.html). Once you have learned how to do that once you will find FileZilla (or perhaps some other FTP client) wonderfully convenient and straightforward for all future server management needs.

1. Connect to old server via FileZilla
2. Download the files
3. Connect to new server via FileZilla
4. Upload the files